# Checking if all elements in array are zero

Tags: c

I'm having trouble determining if two words entered are anagrams.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char ch;
    int letter_count[26] = {0};
    int i;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Enter first word: ");
    do
    {
       scanf("%c", &ch);
       letter_count[ch - 'a']++;
    } while (ch != '\n');
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
      printf("%d ", letter_count[i]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter second word: ");
    do
    {
       scanf("%c", &ch);
       letter_count[ch - 'a']--;
    } while (ch != '\n');
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        printf("%d ", letter_count[i]);
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        if(letter_count[ch] != 0)
            sum++;

    if (sum == 0)
        printf("anagrams");
    else
        printf("not anagrams");
}
```

I have to use the do while part of the code. I can enter the two words, and it prints out the elements in the array, so that "Mattress" and "Smartest" together would have all the elements be zero. However, I'm having trouble with the last part, which is to use a third loop to check whether all the elements are zero.

I figured I could declare an int before hand and have it increment whenever an element wasn't zero, and I could just have any sum greater than zero not be an anagram. However, it always prints out anagram for me.

Comment: Undefined behavior due to out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Replace `sum++` with `bad = true`. And be sure to convert upper-case letters to lower-case.

Comment: @user3386109: Given that `letter_count[ch - 'a']` is accessed *before* the loop-check `ch != ' \n'`, converting `ch` to lowercase doesn't help much.

Comment: Note that in `for(i=0; i < 26; i++)
        if(letter_count[ch] != 0)
            sum++;` your loop increments `i` but you check with `ch` instead of `i`.  This is a major part of your problem.  Don't forget to output a newline after the second lot of letter counts.  And you need to check whether a letter was read before you use the value — if `ch` contains a newline, then you have problems when you use it to set `letter_count` indexed by a negative number, etc.  Revise your input to use `getchar()`.

Comment: @EOF ok, thanks to Jonathan's comment, I get what you're saying, but the OP still has to convert upper-case to lower-case.

Comment: Not checking the return value of scanf() is always asking for surprises. Try typing the end-of-file character to see what I mean.

Comment: Possibly off-topic but since we are talking about anagram detection: if two strings are anagrams, then sorting them both will make them equal. Sort and then check if they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

In your third loop, using `letter_count[ch]` will not check the entire array. You should iterate through the array using the loop variable `i`. That part of the code should be:

```
for (i=0; i<26; i++)
    if (letter_count[i] != 0)
        sum++;
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle both upper case and lower case letters, use `topper()` or `to lower()` in `<ctype.h>` to avoid out-of-bound access.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> // <---

int main() {
    char ch;
    int letter_count[26] = {0};
    int i;
    _Bool bad = 0;

    printf("Enter first word: ");
    do
    {
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        if(!isalpha(ch)) // <---
        {
            puts("Not a letter");
            continue;
        }
        letter_count[tolower(ch) - 'a']++; // <---
    } while (ch != '\n');
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        printf("%d ", letter_count[i]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter second word: ");
    do
    {
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        if(!isalpha(ch)) // <---
        {
            puts("Not a letter");
            continue;
        }
        letter_count[tolower(ch) - 'a']--; // <---
    } while (ch != '\n');
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        printf("%d ", letter_count[i]);
    printf("\n"); // <---

    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        if(letter_count[i] != 0)
        {
            bad = 1;
            break; // <---
        }
    if (bad == 0)
        printf("anagrams");
    else
        printf("not anagrams");
}
```

Take a look at all places marked `// <---`.